# Is it possible to link modules optimized for size with modules optimized for speed with GCC?

Tags: optimization, gcc, linker

Is it possible in GCC to have some modules compiled with -Os and some compiled for -Ofast?

These are C modules in an embedded ARM cortex-M3 system

Comment: Yes (now filling to reach the minimum size for a comment).

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. In practice, most of the time it'll work just fine. Just bear in mind that `-Os` defines `__OPTIMIZE_SIZE__` and `-Ofast` (specifically, `-ffast-math`) defines `__FAST_MATH__` and therefore you can accidentally end up violating the one definition rule.